# Can't find file in Filemanager

Tags: ios, swift

I have a file on my iPhone that I can see in the Files app. However when I look for it in Filemanager with swift I can't find it. I'm in the documents directory and it's not there. I updated the plist for UIFileSharingEnabled and LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace.That didn't help. Anyone know how to get the files that are in the Files App.

Code for documents:

```
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
         let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:  .userDomainMask)
     return paths[0]
     
 }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are *sandboxed*. You cannot programmatically navigate to where this file is. You have to get the *user* to navigate to it for you (in, for example, a UIDocumentPickerViewController).